# How can I mount a USB license dongle on a shared VM in VMware Workstation 9 for Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, vmware-workstation

I currently have VMware Workstation 9 for Linux installed on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop machine. I'm using a Windows XP VM to run some software that requires a USB-based license dongle to run. When I run the VM under my local user account, I can successfully associate the USB-based license dongle with the VM and the software application runs just fine. However, when I share the VM such that other users of the Ubuntu machine can use it, I cannot get the USB-based license dongle to associate with the VM. It shows up in the list of removable devices for the VM and gives me the option to connect it, but it never actually connects.

Is this an issue with Workstation itself, or might it have to do with the license dongle? I know the license dongle doesn't work when I remote desktop to a machine that it works on when using locally, so I'm wondering if accessing the shared VM is similar in some way to accessing the VM via remote desktop.

Comment: have you called the software manufacturer and asked them how to do this?  Sometimes they will tell you how to work around the issue.